# Pattern matching within custom toJson implementation

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, aeson

Let's say I have a type like so:

```
data MyError = CustomError | ProcessExecError !SomeException deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON MyError where
   toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions
```

This fails to compile with:

```
No instance for (ToJSON SomeException)
```

So I rewrite like so:

```
instance ToJSON FlockError where
    toJSON (ProcessExecError _ _) = "ProcessExecError"
    toJSON otherType              = genericToJSON defaultOptions otherType
```

This still fails with:

```
    • No instance for (ToJSON SomeException)
    arising from a use of ‘genericToJSON’
• In the expression: genericToJSON defaultOptions otherType
  In an equation for ‘toJSON’:
      toJSON otherType = genericToJSON defaultOptions otherType
  In the instance declaration for ‘ToJSON FlockError’
 |
47 |     toJSON otherType              = genericToJSON defaultOptions otherType
```

My question is why? Why doesn't the pattern match allow me to write this given that only `ProcessExecError` has a `SomeException` argument?

Comment: Because the type of `otherType` is, still, `MyError`.

Comment: Because you're not following [Parse, don't validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/). You're validating that `otherType` isn't a `ProcessExecError`, but you're then immediately throwing that information away, so `genericToJSON` still has to assume that it might be that.